# Which country does Deutsche Bank AG (NYSE:DB) represent?

Tags: stocks

Deutsche Bank has branches worldwide. Does the NYSE:DB stock represent the performance of the American or the global Deutsche Bank?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the global Deutsche Bank. The stock is listed at both [New York Stock Exchange](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3ADB&ei=m7I4V9GsIIiSUO-mtLgL) and [Frankfurt Stock Exchange](https://www.google.com/finance?q=FRA%3ADBK&ei=e7I4V4HcC4iSUO-mtLgL) (as well as several others). You can see it's the same stock because the long-term chart is practically identical and all the meta-information about the two stocks is identical.

While the Deutsche Bank has [some subsidiaries](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1159508/000119312512122717/d290504dex81.htm) under the *Deutsche Bank* brand in the United States, none of them are publicly traded companies.

And by the way, the Deutsche Bank AG is not the central bank of Germany. That would be the Deutsche **Bundes**bank, which is a completely different organization. The Deutsche Bank is just a normal bank like many others in Germany which managed to secure a very good branding.